# Auto populate dropdown based on previous selection

Tags: php, jquery, forms, select, drop-down-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to dynamically populate options on dropdown lists based on selection in another dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912302/how-to-dynamically-populate-options-on-dropdown-lists-based-on-selection-in-anoth)

I have MySQL tables looking like that

regions table

```
id     |   region
-------------------
1      |   Region1
2      |   Region2
```

...

and schools table

```
id     |   school
-------------------
1      |   schno1
1      |   schno5
1      |   schno6
2      |   scho120
```

There are multiple select (dropdown) menus in my registration form. The regions dropdown looks like that

```
<td>
<select name="region" id="region">
<option value="">Region</option>
<?php
$result=$db->query("SELECT * FROM regions");
while($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
    echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[1].'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>

</td>
<td>
<div id="sch_dropdown">
<select name="school" id="school">
<option value="">School</option>
</select>
</div>
<span id="loading"><img src="core/design/img/jquery-ui/loading.gif" width="16" height="16" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Loading...</span>
<div id="no_sch">No schools found</div>
</td>
```

I want to populate new dropdown list based on previous selections. What i want to do is, get "regions" id, then populate schools dropdown menu based on id (id of previous selection) from "schools" table on the fly.  Here is my code but it doesn't work.

My js looks like that

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function populate() {

       fetch.doPost('core/code/includes/search.php');

}

$('#region').change(populate);

var fetch = function() {

var schools = $('#schools');
return {
    doPost: function(src) {

    $('#loading').show();
    $('#sch_dropdown').hide(); 
    $('#no_sch').hide(); 


        if (src) $.post(src, { region_code: $('#region').val() }, this.getschools);
        else throw new Error('No SRC was passed to getCounties!');
    },

    getschools: function(results) {
        if (!results) return;
        schools.html(results);

    $('#loading').hide(); // Hide the Loading...
    $('#sch_dropdown').show(); // Show the drop down
    }   
}
}();

populate();

});
```

and search.php

```
if(isSet($_POST['region_code'])) {
$res=$db->query("SELECT * FROM schools  WHERE id='".$_POST['region_code']."'");
while ($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[1].'</option>';
}
}
```

Please help me to finish it. Thx in advance.

Comment: @Tural Teyyuboglu take a look at my edited answer

Comment: please anyone help me to get it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `getschools()` with no parameter, so it returns nothing. You were supposed to pass the result that you get after making a POST request to the `search.php` file.

EDIT:
I'm not sure that this will work, as I've not tested it first. But I think you should change

```
  if (src) $.post(src, { region_code: $('#region').val() }, this.getschools);
```

to

```
   if (src) $.post(src, { region_code: $('#region').val() }, function(data){
       getschools(data);
  });
```

Comment: can you edit my wrong piece of code?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2t8pt getting this error

Comment: Try removing the `this` keyword

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2t8w6