# Populate list item elements based on dropdown list choice

Tags: php

I have a course management php page with a database connected in the backend with courses, modules, and modules in a specific course.

I have a form with a dropdown list with options to select a course. Underneath I would like a list of modules in the chosen course from the dropdown list above to show as list item elements. My php code for the form is below. How would I do this using php?

```
    <form method="post" action="courseManagement.php">
                    <table>
                    <center> <span>Course Management<span></center><P><P><P>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Choose course to add module:     </td>
                         <td> <?php
                            $sql = "SELECT courseName FROM course";
                            $result = mysql_query($sql);
                            echo "<select name='courseName'>";
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                    echo "<option value='" . $row['courseName'] ."'>" . $row['courseName'] ."</option>";
                                    }
                                    echo "</select>";
                        ?> 
                    </td>

                        </tr>


                        <tr>
                        <td>
                        Modules in the choosen course
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        <li>Projects and management</li>
                        <li>Programming 2</li>
                        <li>Business Analysis</li>

                        </td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                    <td>Choose module to add to course: </td>
                         <td> <?php
                            $sql = "SELECT moduleName FROM module";
                            $result = mysql_query($sql);
                            echo "<select name='moduleName'>";
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                    echo "<option value='" . $row['moduleName'] ."'>" . $row['moduleName'] ."</option>";
                                    }
                                    echo "</select>";
                        ?> 
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>Choose module to delete from the course: </td>
                         <td> <?php
                            $sql = "SELECT moduleName FROM module";
                            $result = mysql_query($sql);
                            echo "<select name='moduleName'>";
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                    echo "<option value='" . $row['moduleName'] ."'>" . $row['moduleName'] ."</option>";
                                    }
                                    echo "</select>";
                        ?> 
                    </td>
                </tr>



                </table><p><br>

                <center>    
                <input type="submit" value="Update">
                </center>
                </form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically populate options on dropdown lists based on selection in another dropdown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912302/how-to-dynamically-populate-options-on-dropdown-lists-based-on-selection-in-anot)

Comment: sounds like you would benefit by using AJAX.

Comment: Not writing code yet, but I think you will have to use something like jQuery and AJAX and on change event from the select list for the course.  Once the user selects a course you can dynamically generate a list of modules for the course.  That query is going to be dependent upon on you have your tables set up.

Comment: @CodeGodie using AJAX? How so

Comment: yes, check out @sscotti 's comment above. He explains the flow of how it should work with AJAX. Have you ever used it? Have you ever used jQuery?

Comment: @CodeGodie oh okay. No I haven't used jQuery or AJAX yet.

Comment: were you able to figure it out?

Comment: @CodeGodie unfortunately, no

Comment: yeah sure. I have it downloaded now @CodeGodie

Comment: @CodeGodie okay sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can call ajax it's very simple to use this code:

```
SELECT * FROM course;
```

Your dropdown code is something like this:

```
<select name="course" id="course">
   <option value='1'>English</option>
   <option value='2'>Gujarati</option>
</select>
```

Then you want to selectable course by module display in second dropdown, so you can use this in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#course').change(function(){
        var courseid = $(this).val();
        if(courseid != '' && $.isNumeric(courseid)){
            $.post('path of file',{id:courseid}, function(result){
                // usable code //
            }); 
        }
    });
});
```

Then this query write in which file are you call.

```
id = $this->input->post('id');
```

SQL:

```
 SELECT module.*,course.* 
 FROM course 
 LEFT JOIN module ON course.moduleId = module.Id 
 WHERE course.moduleId = id;
```

> You can call this query using ajax call, and you get all list of module by courseid.

Comment: for a beginner with only 9 points, I can say this is a good answer.

Comment: I'd like to select the module by course. If I choose a course from the dropdown list the modules from that course will display underneath

Comment: Why you are not used ajax. it's very simple using ajax. let me explain.